# binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Enemy' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, stl

I'm making a game and I'm trying to find enemies with the bool shouldDie == true.
I have an Enemy std::list and personally I have no idea what's wrong with the code.
If an enemy has shouldDie == true I'll just have an animation playing.
Hopefully you can help me understand why I get the error.

Also I have no overloaded == operator, I've searched online and I'm not sure if it's necessary...

```
bool foundEnemy(Enemy& enemy)
{
    return enemy.shouldDie == true;
}
```

```
void Enemy::PlayDeathAnimation(std::list<Enemy>& enemies)
{
    dead = true;

    auto it = std::find_if(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), foundEnemy); // where I think the error is
    auto enemy = std::next(it, 0);

    if (animationClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.05f)
    {
        enemy->icon.setTextureRect(animationFrames[animationCounter]);
        if (animationCounter >= 8)
        {
            enemies.remove(*enemy);
        }
        animationCounter++;
        animationClock.restart();

    }
}
```

```
class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    Enemy() {}
    Enemy(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Texture* texture,Player* target);
    ~Enemy();

    void Update(sf::RenderWindow* window, float tElapsedTime);
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow* window);
    void Fire(float tElapsedTime);
    void CheckBullets();
    void CheckEnemyBullets();
    void CheckHealth();

    void SetPosition(float x, float y);

    bool shouldDie = false;

    void PlayDeathAnimation(std::list<Enemy>& enemies);



private:

    bool dead = false;

    sf::Texture* deathSpriteSheet;
    std::vector<sf::IntRect> animationFrames;

    std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
    sf::RectangleShape origin;
    sf::RectangleShape aim;
    Player* target;

    int animationCounter = 0;
    sf::Clock animationClock;

};
```

Comment: What is `shouldDie`? Can you show us the `Enemy` header?

Comment: it is a public bool member of Enemy class

Comment: Well then either you've shown us the wrong piece of code or your compiler is wrong, since it's complaining about a `==` with an `Enemy` as the left hand operand. (Also pro-tip, `return enemy.shouldDie == true;` can just be `return enemy.shouldDie;`. You never have to compare to a boolean literal)

Comment: I'll check again

Comment: In case nothing found, it returns enemies.end(), and in this case your code will have issue.

Comment: @scohe001 that piece of code looks weird, but it is technically ok.

Comment: @Tony I agree. That's why I think we're being shown the wrong piece of code here ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is actually not where you think it is, but few lines below.

```
if (animationCounter >= 8)
{
    enemies.remove(*enemy); // here
}
```

You are using `std::list::remove` function, which will search for any elements of the list matching given element and removes those. To know which element is the same as given, it needs to know how to compare them, thus the need for `operator ==`

Use [`std::list::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) instead - this function accepts an iterator and will remove exact element you point to.

```
if (animationCounter >= 8)
{
    enemies.erase(enemy); // no dereference of the iterator
}
```

---

Side note - compiler is *very* useful tool. If it detects an error, it will point you to a direct line and column where it occurred, although sometimes this piece of information is very well hidden in a ton of other (less useful) prints.

If you don't understand the language of the compiler (yet), you can copy and paste the whole error message into your SO question, this will help us diagnose error faster.